# Can you set dynamic json struct field tags?

Tags: json, go, marshalling, unmarshalling

I have for example this struct that I will unmarshal data into:

```
type SomeAnimal struct {
  Animal string `json:"animal"`
}
```

I have a case where I would like `animal` to be a variable I can pass in, such that my program is configurable and that the json is not hardcoded to use `animal`. For example, this code is not valid but is what I am seeking to do:

```
jsonFieldName := "animal"
type SomeAnimal struct {
   Animal string `json:jsonFieldName`
}
```

CustomMarshalJSON does not seem to accomplish what I am looking to do here. Is there a way to do such a thing on golang?

Comment: you could implement `json.Marshaler` interface and do it yourself

Comment: Go is a statically typed language, you can't change the tags of a struct dynamically at runtime. Using reflection you can, at runtime, create new struct types with new tags, but you cannot change the tags of existing type. You need to come up with a different X for your Y.

Comment: What are you doing with the Json struct tag, is it just to change how it’s displayed when marshalled as json. If so you could have a custom marshal function that looks for a ‘key’ struct tag (via reflection), something like custom-myVar then you can split on the hyphen and then perhaps passes that myVar to a map to find the relevant output tag? Seems brittle though...